# what does it mean disallowed character in URI?

Tags: codeigniter, printing, continuous-integration, anchor

i have written this in my view page,

```
<a onclick="window.open('print_mine/id=<?php echo $value['id'];?>','800','400')">View</a>
```

it is giving me The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

i need id in other page

i have written code in route.php as well as in controller

Comment: Post the exact error message.  But as to the title question "disallowed character in URI" typically means you're trying to use a URI that contains characters that are not allowed.

Comment: An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: What does `$value['id']` actually _expand_ to? Can you paste the full expanded URI that's throwing this? You probably have a bug somewhere else that's putting something you probably don't want into your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your config/config.php and search for "disallowed" or "illegal". There you have some chars that are disallowed in CIs URIs.
Maybe you want to `window.open('print_mine/<?=$value['id']?>','800','400')`?

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

Sholud i change in this??

And what is the change?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I mean. There are all chars that are allowed. The "=" is not in there - you could add it.

But why do you need the "="?

Answer (score 0):

Your view:

```
<a onclick="window.open('print_mine/<?php echo $value['id'];?>','800','400')">View</a>
```

In controller:

```
function print_mine(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3); #will fetch the third segment
}
```